# Truffle - Pet Shop - Errors on All Tests (.sol)

Tags: javascript, node.js, truffle, ganache

I am following the pet shop [tutorial on Truffle](https://trufflesuite.com/tutorial/index.html#testing-the-smart-contract-using-solidity). The first few steps work, i.e., I can compile and migrate the Adoption contract. My software versions are:

Truffle v5.4.33 (core: 5.4.33)
Ganache v7.0.1
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v17.6.0
Web3.js v1.5.3

Adoption contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {

        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 5);

        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

        return petId;    
    }

    function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
        return adopters;
    }
}
```

Migrations folder:
1_initial_migration.js

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var Adoption = artifacts.require("Adoption");

    module.exports = function(deployer) {
        deployer.deploy(Adoption);
    }
```

Compilation and migration (after launching Ganache 2.5.4):

```
x@x:~/Code/Blockchain/Truffle/pet-shop-tutorial$ truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

x@x:~/Code/Blockchain/Truffle/pet-shop-tutorial$ truffle migrate

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Replacing 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   ⠋ Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0   > transaction hash:    0x32545eb8f57d03e0a90b9fc14e7e193c936632be84401a7ecc1481294c766ef4
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0xC7801C9570FD9Dfb9dFca6f29461D2Dd3e8b813e
   > block number:        1
   > block timestamp:     1646245076
   > account:             0xdFd735b7b2a4Cf28Bb7A85E2366FC73522573f8e
   > balance:             99.99616114
   > gas used:            191943 (0x2edc7)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00383886 ETH


   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00383886 ETH


2_deploy_contracts.js
=====================

   Replacing 'Adoption'
   --------------------
   ⠋ Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0   > transaction hash:    0x17f512c4fdabc0b743b2b552352059275c64969f728ae23874d3fc162c9c4a27
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x9E552555C766a1E1FdB5823FC3F0301C04C79651
   > block number:        3
   > block timestamp:     1646245078
   > account:             0xdFd735b7b2a4Cf28Bb7A85E2366FC73522573f8e
   > balance:             99.99123784
   > gas used:            203827 (0x31c33)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00407654 ETH


   > Saving migration to chain.
   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:          0.00407654 ETH

Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   2
> Final cost:          0.0079154 ETH
```

The top line in Ganache then says Tx count of 4, like the tutorial says, and some ETH is deducted from that address.

The problems arise at testing. I have copied and pasted the tests (both .Sol and .Js) to ensure no typos but they are compiling so I don't think that's it.

But here is the TestAdoption.sol code (in the test folder)"

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {

        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 5);

        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

        return petId;    
    }

    function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
        return adopters;
    }
}
```

And the errors I get:

```
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./test/TestAdoption.sol
> Artifacts written to /tmp/test--7680-8QYwuQbGOkD1
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang



  TestAdoption
    1) testUserCanAdoptPet
    > No events were emitted
    2) testGetAdopterAddressByPetId
    > No events were emitted
    3) testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (37s)
  3 failing

  1) TestAdoption
       testUserCanAdoptPet:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:91:1)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

  2) TestAdoption
       testGetAdopterAddressByPetId:
     Error: Owner of the expected pet should be this contract
      at checkResultForFailure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:65:1)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:91:1)

  3) TestAdoption
       testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray:
     Error: Owner of the expected pet should be this contract
      at checkResultForFailure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:65:1)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/SolidityTest.js:91:1)
```

[Edit: I made errors copying the JS test, removed, if errors persist after getting it and the other error noted in the answer right I'll post seperately.]

Could anyone point me in the right direction to get these tests working?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contract requires only pets with IDs between 0 and 5 can be adopted:

```
require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 5);
```

Yet on your test, you are adopting a pet with `petId` of 8:

```
await adoption.adopt(8, { from: accounts[0] });
```

Try adopting a pet with `petId` between 0 and 5 in your test.

Comment: Thank you. I meant "15" there.  Can you point me to any resources/methods for help debugging smart contracts (i.e,, ways of getting info that would actually point me to the bad line like a normal traceback)?

Comment: I believe the [Truffle Debugger](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/using-the-truffle-debugger.html) should be able to help you with this.